# Read and Write in File with Assembly MASM

Tags: assembly

I Want to Write and Read from file(.txt) in Assembly MASM (80X86 assembly) with "create" method in microsoft.com .
Note That I Do not want to use "Interrupt".
Thanks

Comment: I asked here , because I thought you can help me , bro.

Comment: this is how to ask here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You "must" use the OS (windows in your case) API's to deal with the files , no matter witch language do you use, they all will eventually use the OS API's inside their implementations  . but before that and as for assembly you will need to..

1- include the kernel32.inc file into your .asm source code(or prototype the function do you need to call).

2- make sure you included the kernel32.lib file into your linker input files.

3- then you can call the file API's like [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank You Very much , It is so helpful.